# atom editor crashed and showing the open file blank

Tags: crash, atom-editor

I was working on a PHP file in atom editor. system shutdown due to power fluctuation. When I restarted the system and opened the file to see that it was all blank. File size shows 47kb. All the characters are somehow replaced by invisible characters. I can move the cursor left and right, up and down through these invisible characters.

Comment: Are you able to open the file in for example notepad and see your code?

Comment: No..It showing blank but size of file remains same.

Comment: Sounds like you need to go back to a backup unfortunanly...